# Inconsistent XML notation in Qt

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I am using Qt and C++ to read/write XML files. There is a weird behavior although I use only Qt classes.

```
QDomDocument document;

QDomElement element = document.createElement( "QString" );

QDomText textNode = document.createTextNode( "" ); // Empty string.
element.appendChild( textNode );
```

Sometimes the result in the XML file is `<QString/>` and sometimes it is `<QString></QString>`. Does anyone know why does this happen?

Comment: In XML both of these strings are equivalent. It shouldn't bother you too much :)

Comment: Okay, I know that. But sometimes I need to compare the before/after versions of the `XML`s, and these (not real) differences makes it harder.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev: true, but one or the other form should be preferred. Usually software doesn't decide such things at random.

Comment: Could this be one of the reasons `QDomDocument` is deprecated? (Per http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtxml-module.html#details) – I know, you are stuck with this code for now. Can't the answer be found in the QT source code?

Comment: @Jongware I strongly agree :) I'm not saying it is not a reasonable question. Anything that gives different output for the same input arouses interest, at least.

Comment: I found `QDomDocument` also unhandy when it comes to whitespace in text nodes. Technically, `<a><b/></a>` is a different DOM document than `<a> <b/> </a>` but Qt makes the latter out of the former if you enable automatic indentation. Very annoying, too.

Comment: Is it at least deterministic for a given example?

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld I'll try to find out. But as I remember when the original XML contained the short version then the new XML would contain the long, but I really need to check this.

Comment: Searching `qdom.cpp` for where an element name gets `"/"` appended at the end, the **single** result is inside `void QDomElementPrivate::save`, and done when the data part is empty. However, I cannot readily locate what happens to an empty string as 'data' – is it stored as a string (with a zero length), or does it get discarded? This "cleanup" could have happened at any moment in the entire code.

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't provide a [MCVE](/help/mcve), I wrote:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDomDocument>
#include <QDomElement>
#include <QDomText>

int main()
{
    QDomDocument document;
    for (int i = 0;  i < 15;  ++i) {
        QDomElement element = document.createElement("QString");
        element.setAttribute("n", i);
        if (i%2)
            element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(QString()));
        document.appendChild(element);
    }

    qDebug() << qPrintable(document.toString());
}
```

This consistently produces

```
<QString n="0"/>
<QString n="1"></QString>
<QString n="2"/>
<QString n="3"></QString>
<QString n="4"/>
<QString n="5"></QString>
<QString n="6"/>
<QString n="7"></QString>
<QString n="8"/>
<QString n="9"></QString>
<QString n="10"/>
<QString n="11"></QString>
<QString n="12"/>
<QString n="13"></QString>
<QString n="14"/>
```

The shorttag version is produced only when the element has no content, and the full open+close when there is content, even if that is a `QDomText` with an empty string.